# "lo que nos causó" or "lo que nos ha causado". Which one is correct?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

In the text below, which is a slightly edited translation from a Brazilian Portuguese text using Google Translate, can both expressions "lo que nos causó" and "lo que nos ha causado" be used?  Or, as a broader question, does this translation make any sense at all?

> A partir de ahora intentemos ser más amables y educados. Ofensas y
> agresiones tú bien sabes **lo que nos causó** / **lo que nos ha
> causado**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence:

> Ofensas y agresiones tú bien sabes lo que nos causó / lo que nos ha causado.

is ungrammatical for two reasons:

1. We don't usually use the zero article for nouns in subject position.
2. There is no agreement between plural "ofensas y agresiones" and the verb in the singular (either "causó" or "ha causado").

To better understand the sentence, which is a clear case of [hyperbaton](https://literaryterms.net/hyperbaton/) used for emphasis, we can reorder it as follows:

- Tú bien sabes lo que **las** ofensas y (**las**) agresiones nos **causaron / han causado**.

In line with (1) above, the subject "las ofensas y (las) agresiones" needs to have a determiner, in this case, the definite article, and in line with (2), the verb has to be in the plural form.

Both "causaron" and "han causado" are correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the amazing explanation, it really makes sense. And also thanks for the tip on the use of hyperbaton. Really helpful.